# Adding arrays indexes with integers

Tags: arrays, int, addition

I am working on a problem where I have to calculate frequencies of characters in a text. I havent coded in a while and am a little rusty so I thought it would help to get a second pair of eyes on my code. 
my code reads in a file and ideally it should hit my if statements and add "1" to my frequency array.  However, it always prints "0". Am I not adding correctly?

```
public class hw4{
public static void main (String []args)throws IOException{

//ask user to enter file name
System.out.printf("Enter a file location and name to encode [press Enter]: ");

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String filename = input.next();

//Gets file name from Scanner and checks to see if valid
File file = new File(filename);
Scanner text = new Scanner(file);

String[] letters = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"};
int[] freq = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

String letter;

    while(text.hasNext()){
        letter = text.next();

        if (letter == "a"){
        freq[0] = freq[0] + 1;
        }
        if (letter == "b"){
        freq[1] = freq[1] + 1;
        }
        if (letter == "c"){
        freq[2] = freq[2] + 1;
        }
        if (letter == "d"){
        freq[3] = freq[3] + 1;
        }
        if (letter == "e"){
        freq[4] = freq[4] + 1;
        }
        if (letter == "f"){
        freq[5] = freq[5] + 1;
        }
        if (letter == "g"){
        freq[6] = freq[6] + 1;
        }
        if (letter == "h"){
        freq[7] = freq[7] + 1;
        }
        if (letter == "i"){
        freq[8] = freq[8] + 1;
        }
        if (letter == "j"){
        freq[9] = freq[9] + 1;
        }
        if (letter == "k"){
        freq[10] = freq[10] + 1;
        }
        if (letter == "l"){
        freq[11] = freq[11] + 1;
        }
        if (letter == "m"){
        freq[12] = freq[12] + 1;
        }
        if (letter == "n"){
        freq[13] = freq[13] + 1;
        }
        if (letter == "o"){
        freq[14] = freq[14] + 1;
        }
        if (letter == "p"){
        freq[15] = freq[15] + 1;
        }
        if (letter == "q"){
        freq[16] = freq[16] + 1;
        }
        if (letter == "r"){
        freq[17] = freq[17] + 1;
        }
        if (letter == "s"){
        freq[18] = freq[18] + 1;
        }
        if (letter == "t"){
        freq[19] = freq[19] + 1;
        }
        if (letter == "u"){
        freq[20] = freq[20] + 1;
        }
        if (letter == "v"){
        freq[21] = freq[21] + 1;
        }
        if (letter == "w"){
        freq[22] = freq[22] + 1;
        }
        if (letter == "x"){
        freq[23] = freq[23] + 1;
        }
        if (letter == "y"){
        freq[24] = freq[24] + 1;
        }
        if (letter == "z"){
        freq[25] = freq[25] + 1;
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i <26; i++){
    System.out.printf("%s:%d\n", letters[i], freq[i]);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You'll need to specify what language this is. That will affect the answer very significantly.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that there is an equivalency issue.

the check is not

if(letter == "a")

but

if(letter.equals("A")